# Convert PDF to XSL-FO

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo

I need to generate PDF using XSL-FO, and I have already got the outcome PDF file. Is there any tool that can convert PDF file back to XSL-FO? I know the converted one won't be ready- to-use, but it will give me a good start, and I won't need to handle too many style stuffs.

Any help is welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: If the document is a static one, meaning the variable data is all stamped in certain positions (like a form would be), then you could also consider generating that PDF without any data. Then use that PDF as a background image and create a simple XSL to put your variable data down on top. Depending on the amount of formatting that is the "background" (static) information, this can be much more performant than formatting it every time.

Comment: The thing is it's a dynamic one, and contains a table with variable rows, so I have to use XML and XSL, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, but if you have the PDF, do you not have the XSL FO that created it? That seems so confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at AHPDFXML (https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/ahpdfxml-conversion-library/).  It will give you an XML version of the content and styles in the PDF.

Comment: No, it's not free.